# try throw exception handling

Tags: c++, exception, segmentation-fault, try-catch, stack

I'm having a little trouble with making the following piece of code work. I cannot write a throw exception so I don't know what else could I do.

```
case 't':  // Top of Stack
             try
             {
               cout << "Top() -- " << sPtr->Top() << endl; //this should run if the stack is not empty.
             }
             catch (StackEmpty)
             {
               cout << "Top() -- Failed Empty Stack" << endl; // this should run if the stack is empty.
             }
             break;
```

the sPtr points to Top() Function in a Class name Stack here is the code for that function:

```
int Stack::Top() const  // Returns value of top integer on stack WITHOUT modifying the stack
{   cout << "*Top Start" << endl;
if(!IsEmpty())
return topPtr->data;
cout << "*Top End" << endl;
}
```

if I remove the if statement it causes a segmentation fault problem.

Comment: When learning to code C++, examine every `if` without `else` and make _really_ sure that's what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually throwing anything on failure, and in the case when the stack is empty you're just running off the end of the function without returning anything. Also your final log statement is only hit when the stack is empty.

You need something more like this:

```
int Stack::Top() const  // Returns value of top integer on stack WITHOUT modifying the stack
{ 
  cout << "*Top Start" << endl;
  if(!IsEmpty())
  {
     cout << "*Top End" << endl;
     return topPtr->data;
  }
  cout << "*Top End" << endl;
  throw StackEmpty();
}
```

Comment: perfect! I could have sworn I had tried that at least two different times, two different ways and it was giving me an error, but anyways thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Why "can't" you throw an exception? Note that if you don't return anything from `Top()` (when your stack is empty) you are asking for trouble to happen. It should be a precondition to `Top()` that the stack is not empty, so if you can't throw an exception an assert would be acceptable, even preferable at least to me.

By the way, exceptions are thrown like this:

```
throw StackEmpty();
```